# Unable to hit API Endpoint containing generic type

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a Web API, its working fine except one endpoint and returning 404 for the same. Below is my code here I am using generic type to add 2 input parameters.

**Method:**

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet("{number1}/{number2}")]
    [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
    public dynamic AddTwoInputs<T>(T number1, T number2)
    {
        dynamic a = number1;
        dynamic b = number2;
        return a + b;
    }
```

I am trying to hit it from postman **Get** method with URL "domain/**api/Users/AddTwoInputs/1/2**".
Please suggest the solution.

Comment: Would using `int` for each parameter be an option? The add operation will only work with numbers or strings so using another data type will fail anyway. Using `dynamic` is a dangerous construction that provides limited safety.

Comment: its intended to add numbers while concatenate strings.

Answer (score 1):

Quite sure that aspnet just ignores the method as generic types are not going to work for controller methods.

Your code is a good example why. The url is just a string and there's no way of knowing for your API what parameter type you intend it to be. If it's intended to be numbers you'll get the result `3`. If it's a string it'll result in `12`.

Comment: you are right, its intended to add numbers while concatenate strings..

Comment: so there s no way to use generics in Controller method?

Comment: @SunilChaudhry For generic action methods you can't. As said there's no way for your class to infer what data type is used. You could retrieve it as a string which always works (since the url is a string) and parse it afterwards but that'll result in the same issue. You can't infer if a string with only numbers is intended as string or integer (or some other data type).